# Prevent default action on mouse click

Tags: mouseevent, autoit, mouseclick-event

I want `MsgBox()` on mouse click, but prevent natural behaviour of mouse click. That means if I click any links here on Stack Overflow my active page must remain the same.

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#Include <Misc.au3>

While 1
    If _IsPressed(01) Then ShowAlert() ; 01 is for left mouse button
    Sleep (100)
WEnd

Func ShowAlert()
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Test")
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <Constants.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Global Const $HC_ACTION = 0
Global $hStub_MouseProc = DllCallbackRegister("_MouseProc", "long", "int;wparam;lparam")
Global $hmod = _WinAPI_GetModuleHandle(0)
Global $hHook = _WinAPI_SetWindowsHookEx($WH_MOUSE_LL, DllCallbackGetPtr($hStub_MouseProc), $hmod)

HotKeySet('^+!e', '_ende') ; CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+E to exit.
OnAutoItExitRegister('ExitFunc')

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func _ende()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>_ende

Func _MouseProc($nCode, $wParam, $lParam)
    If $nCode < 0 Then
        Return _WinAPI_CallNextHookEx($hHook, $nCode, $wParam, $lParam)
    EndIf
    If $nCode = $HC_ACTION Then
        Switch $wParam
            Case 0x0201
                ConsoleWrite('No Click!' & @CRLF)
                Return -1
;~          Case $WM_MBUTTONUP
;~              Return _mouse_event($MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP) ; Returns -1; mouse click will be ignored.
        EndSwitch
    EndIf
    Return _WinAPI_CallNextHookEx($hHook, $nCode, $wParam, $lParam)
EndFunc   ;==>_MouseProc

Func ExitFunc()
    _WinAPI_UnhookWindowsHookEx($hHook)
    DllCallbackFree($hStub_MouseProc)
EndFunc   ;==>ExitFunc

Func _mouse_event($dwFlags)
    DllCall("user32", 'long', 'mouse_event', 'long', $dwFlags, 'long', 0, 'long', 0, 'long', 0, 'long', 0)
    Return -1
EndFunc   ;==>_mouse_event
```

Answer (score 0):

> … prevent it's natural behaviour in the same time …

As per [MouseOnEvent UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/64738-mouseonevent-udf/):

> This UDF allows to set an events handler for Mouse device.

Example (using `ConsoleWrite()` as `MsgBox()` requires the blocked mouse-click in order to be closed):

```
#include "MouseOnEvent.au3"

Global Const $g_sKeyQuit    = '{esc}'
Global Const $g_iDelay      = 10
Global Const $g_bBlockInput = True

Global       $g_bStateQuit  = False

Main()

Func Main()
    HotKeySet($g_sKeyQuit, 'Quit')
    _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_PRIMARYDOWN_EVENT, '_MousePrimaryDown_Event')
    _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_PRIMARYDBLCLK_EVENT, '_MousePrimaryDblclk_Event')

    While Not $g_bStateQuit
        Sleep($g_iDelay)
    WEnd

    Exit
EndFunc

Func Quit()
    $g_bStateQuit = True
EndFunc

Func _MousePrimaryDown_Event()
    ConsoleWrite('Detected $MOUSE_PRIMARYDOWN_EVENT' & @CRLF)
    Return $g_bBlockInput ? $MOE_BLOCKDEFPROC : $MOE_RUNDEFPROC
EndFunc

Func _MousePrimaryDblclk_Event()
    ConsoleWrite('Detected $MOUSE_PRIMARYDBLCLK_EVENT' & @CRLF)
    Return $g_bBlockInput ? $MOE_BLOCKDEFPROC : $MOE_RUNDEFPROC
EndFunc
```

The UDF allows events to be registered to a specific window as well. It can either block or pass events after detection and includes example on how to restrict functionality to part(s) of a screen.